# Laravel Migration to change table name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to change my two table name in the Laravel, so do I have to manually change the table name or it can be possible through migration.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

from the docs [laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables)

To change a table name, you can do this:

```
Schema::rename($currentTableName, $newTableName);
```

You can use the `drop` or `dropIfExists` methods to remove an existing table:

```
Schema::drop('users');

Schema::dropIfExists('users');
```

Just add that to a migration and it should work.

Comment: Will this also rename/change the Controllers/Models?

Comment: > Will this also rename/change the Controllers/Models?

No.

Comment: Instead of renaming all your classes, you can use this line to tell your model to use a different table:
`protected $table = 'tablename';`

Comment: What classes do I need to change to work the Model as it is without adding the `protected $table = 'tablename';` line?

Answer (score 87):

You can rename table like that

```
Schema::rename('old_table', 'new_table');
```

**BUT** be careful if you have `foreign keys`, `indexes` and `unique-s`.

you will not be able to deleted them after renaming, like thiat

```
Schema::table('new_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->dropForeign(['transaction_id']);
 });
```

because they will have old names and these names have table name in them.

Thus, I recommend deleting `foreign keys` and other stuff first

```
 Schema::table('old_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['transaction_id']);
 });

 Schema::rename('old_table', 'new_table');

 Schema::table('new_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('transaction_id')->references('id')->on('transactions');
 });
```

Comment: +1 for Foreign Keys. I think the same would apply for indexes as they are also automatically named by Laravel (if you don't specify a name).

Comment: yes, The indexes would be "other stuff" that I mentioned.

Comment: there is a way to do it, and a properly way to do it covering edge cases ! this should be the accepted answer !

Answer (score 27):

Firstly, use CLI command to create a migration:

```
php artisan make:migration rename_table
```

Now, in the up method of the new migration class, use the rename method to change table name:

```
Schema::rename('old_table_name', 'new_table_name');
```

Next, execute the migration command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, run this in your terminal to create a migration file to rename a table:

```
php artisan make:migration rename_old_name_to_new_name_table
```

Then in the up method, you should have this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::rename('old_table_name', 'new_table_name');
}
```

Then in the down method, you should have this in case you want to revert previous changes made:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::rename('new_table_name', 'old_table_name');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To rename an existing database table, use the rename method:

```
Schema::rename($from, $to);
```

To drop an existing table, you may use the drop or `dropIfExists` methods:

```
Schema::drop('users');

Schema::dropIfExists('users');
```

Comment: you are just copying an existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33889923/13050909