# How to customize laravel user Migration to new

Tags: php, laravel, migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone_number')->nullable();
        $table->text('Biography')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->string('facebook_link')->nullable();
        $table->string('twitter_link')->nullable();
        $table->string('youtube_link')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I would like to changed the user to another name but could not and migration is not working.

Comment: what you mean by this **i would like to changed the user to another name**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Migration to change table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888599/laravel-migration-to-change-table-name)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [rename the table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables), you can create a new migration with this code:

```
Schema::rename('users', 'some_other_table_name');
```

Then run `composer du` and `php artisan migrate` commands.

Or, you could recreate the table by rolling back this migration `php artisan migrate:rollback` whcih will work if you have this line in the `down()` method:

```
Schema::drop('users');
```

Change the table name:

```
Schema::create('some_other_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
```

And then run `php artisan migrate`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations

Comment: but due to migration and auth its not working , after renaming migration of user table is not possible

Comment: @Najibjamshidi you asked how to rename the table, I've answered that. To use different table for auth system, just change provider in `config/auth.php`