# How to migrate old MySQL database into Laravel Project?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to migrate an old PHP/MySQL to Laravel project. For so many reasons I'm should not modify the database table schema.  I need to modify the Laravel framework classes. For example, I want to force Laravel Auth to check the `users.USER` capitalize column to return the user, instead of `users.user`.  I need to know which part of the Laravel framework check the `users` database table or `user` column. How to modify without break the default Auth functionality.

More specific: I want to know how Laravel retrieve data from database in `/Vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php` line 137 `validateCredentials()`.

Comment: Why don't you write migration scripts? e.g You can migrate `users.USER` to `users.user` column in your migration script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33889923/823549

Comment: You can also use custom model for authentication, i.e. a table other than `users`. See [this](https://medium.com/@ZtuX/how-to-change-your-authentication-model-in-laravel-5-3-7a580a727d6f) post for more details.

Comment: if your current table schema has the  main columns i.e name, password, email; then in the Users table you can just specify the table property by  passing the table name there and laravel will automatically pick that

Comment: @john My goal is to force Laravel Auth to use my `users.USER` column instead of checking the `users.user` table. I don't want to change my table schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Database considetations

If you want to use your custom database on your laravel application, you just have to make a Model for each of the tables of your database and set up the table name, primary key and fillable attributes.

More info here [Defining Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models)

### Authentication with custom user and pass fields

If you runned the command `php artisan make:auth` but you want to use another table or fields instead of the default user and pass without breaking the created Auth functionality, you have to make laravel to know it, following the steps listed bellow:

**First:** Create a Model for the table that you want to use for authentication. To do it, run the command `php artisan make:model FooUserTable`, where 'FooUser' is the name of your table.

Next you have to set on the model your table name, primary key and fillable fields, like bellow:

```
class FooUser extends Authenticatable{

    protected $table = 'FooUser';
    protected $primaryKey = 'foo_id_user'; // Place here the name of the id of your table
    protected $fillable = [ // Insert here all the fillable fields of your users table
        'field1',
        'field2',
        ...
    ];

}
```

Note that the model now extends from Authenticatable instead of model, that is an alias for the class `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`. In order to make it works, just put `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable` at the top of your file.

This is important!:

In order to use another field name for the password, place the function `getAuthPassword` into the model for your users table, like bellow:

```
public function getAuthPassword(){
    return $this->myPasswordField; // myPasswordField is the field on your users table for password
}
```

Now you have all of your model ready for the next step.

**Second:** On the file `config > auth.php` you have to find the providers array, and change the model property value to your model class name, for example:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\FooUser::class, // Place here the name of your model
    ],
],
```

All ready for the next step.

**Third:** Now you have to find the controller for the default Laravel Auth, located into `app > http > controllers > auth > LoginController.php`, and into the class, you only have to add a function called `username` that returns the username to be used for the auth action, like bellow:

```
class LoginController extends Controller{

    ..... // don't change other functions

    public function username(){ // add the function username
        return 'YourUsernameField';
    }

}
```

**Blade login template note:** In your login blade template, you should change the username input name to the new one, and the password field name must be still `password`, thats because laravel use it for validation, but internally it's going to use your custom password field name.

And that's all. I hope this helps you.

**Note:** Never edit the files into the vendor folder!

For more information, read the documentation on the section [Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users)

All of this was tested on Laravel 5.4 and 5.7 versions.

Comment: I personally think it's overkill to what he's trying to achieve. 
But it's a very well structured and detailed answer. 

It's also more an answer to the question of how to extend properly.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create all models for the table and relations. On the models you can specify a table name, you don't have to rename the tables if you don't want to.

for example.

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model{
    protected $table = 'users.USER';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Database Related Question/Answer:***

For extracting Models out of a Database Scheme you can use the following package:

[Reliese/Laravel](https://github.com/reliese/laravel)

This package makes it possible to automatically generate the Eloquent Models you need to start working with your database in Laravel.

It has a bunch of easy to use commands to be able to make models from your Database Scheme.

**Usage**

Let's scaffold some of your models from your default connection.

```
php artisan code:models
```

You can scaffold a specific table like this:

```
php artisan code:models --table=users
```

You can also specify the connection:

```
php artisan code:models --connection=mysql
```

If you are using a MySQL database, you can specify which schema you want to scaffold:

```
php artisan code:models --schema=shop
```

***Extending/Editing Auth Functionality***

Take a look at the official documentation about [manually authenticating](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users).

If you place the following snippet in your Controller:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

If you need to specify which properties to use you can use the following:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
  // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

You could also just do your own check and then login in your code directly with the following code:

```
Auth::login($user);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::login($user, true);
```

Everything I listed here is in the link above about authenticating users.