# Changing laravel database table name

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have a website script purchased which used laravel. Then the developer updated it but did not work on the script (like changing the database table name) but changed the database table name.

Now by hitting the button shows error like no database table found.

[image: Table name differ from]

Like the old script contains "page" table and the updated version contains the same name on all scripts but in MySQL table name got changed with "web_page".

I know I can simply go and change the table name on MySQL database, so everything will work fine.
But I am seeing other the same. So I want to fix the table name on script not going to phpmyadmin.

So, where can I find it to fix? I hope you understood what I want to say.

Comment: change table name on model

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888599/laravel-migration-to-change-table-name

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you can override the table name:

```
class Page extends Model {

    protected $table = "web_page";

}
```