# nested data structure in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a users_table and user_tweets_table in Laravel / MySQL.I want to return response data in this structure:

```
[
{
id:1,
name:'Johne',
tweets:[
{
id:1,
content:"something"
},
{
id:2,
content"something else"
}
]
},
{
id:2,
name:'Jennifer',
tweets:[
{
id:1,
content:"something"
},
{
id:2,
content"something else"
}
]
},
]
```

I try this one but it's not good:

```
  $list = User::all();
    $list = $list->
    skip($skip)->
    take($take);
    foreach ($list as $user)
    {

        $user['tweets']=UserTweet::where('user_id',$user['id'])->get();
    }
    return response(['message' => 'The list of users', 'data' => $list], 200);
```

how can I do that with eloquent and innerjoin?

Comment: what did you try? add some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should build the relation between your models ...

in User Model:

```
  public function tweets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserTweet::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

in UserTweet Model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }
```

now  you can [load](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) your relation:

```
$list = User::with('tweets')->all();
```

more about one to many relation in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: very nice, i have another issue:i wanna chance the table name for example from tweets to comments.How can i do that

Comment: you can see the answer here, it's very nice one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33889923/10573560

Comment: no I dont want really change the table name if want rename the key in the returned data fom tweets to comments!

Comment: just rename the relation ...  public function comments() {.......} and then $list = User::with('comments')->all();